# How to use the ChoiceListInterface in Symfony 2?

Tags: forms, symfony, multiple-choice

I'd like to display a dynamic list of checkboxes in a form.

So far, I built a form embedding a static list of checkboxes, and I created a Tag entity for different values in different languages and populated the database. I'd like to replace the static checkboxes by a dynamic list based on the Tag entity.

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-list) says I should use the ChoiceListInterface. But it is really poorly documented. Would you have an example or a global logic explanation to help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend [LazyChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php#L25) abstract class and implement [loadChoiceList()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php#L137) method, create a service of it, inject it to the form and set it as `choice_list` option.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks difficult to implement ; I didn't find any examples of this on Google :(

Comment: @Yako It's pretty easy. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313415/symfony2-populate-choice-list-from-api-data :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used an entity field type :

```
->add('tags', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'bndMyBundle:Tag',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->orderBy('t.en', 'ASC');
            },
            'expanded'   => true,
            'multiple'  => true,
            'property'  => 'en',
        ))
```

Then, I just need to replace the 'en' value by the user's current locale to choose the right language.

Comment: Hey Yako, this answer does not address the question at all - it should not be marked as accepted. The one from @m2mdas addresses the question. His answer is maybe too short, but it's strictly relevant to the question. I think you should unaccept it and either accept m2mdas's answer or do not accept any and wait for a better explanation. (Just my side note with good intention)