# Symfony2 populate choice list from api data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have to populate a choice list from an Api call. I have try several approach without success.

I think the best way is by implementing ChoiceListInterface.

Does someone has already done it ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you actually tried?

Comment: I've just answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285281/from-doctrine-query-to-querybuilder-in-a-simfony2-entity-field-type/13285719#13285719
See the "UPDATE" section of the answer...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Extend [LazyChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php#L25) and implement [loadChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php#L137) method, e.g

```
//ApiChoiceList.php
namespace Your\Namespace;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;

class ApiChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList 
{
    protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        //fetch and process api data

        return new ChoiceList($choices, $labels);

    }
}
```

And then in your `buildForm` method of your form,

```
$builder->add('fieldname', 'choice', array(
    'choice_list' => new Your\Namespace\ApiChoiceList(),
    //....
));
```

Comment: +1 @m2mdas, this is great. Just a quick question. The ApiChoiceList will contain all the choices that will be used in the form. Is there anything to do in the entity to make sure the data suits the ApiChoiceList?

Comment: Might want to add the extra awesome choice list as service to your answer. :)

Comment: how to use this choice list in the twig view to display the value in the showAction?