# how to load data from database to my own custom field type (form)

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to create a custom form field. For example, select field of cities in the world.
I read this article. In this article, the data are loaded using parameter file config.ynl. I, however, I'd like to upload this data from my database.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Can somebody tell me how to do this or send the link to the example

Comment: For choice field see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13320439/1218997).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, better is to use an [Entity Field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html) instead of a Choice Field. It allows you to request your database to load your entities as follow,

```
$builder->add('MyField', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:MyEntity',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('e');
    },
    'property' => 'something',
));
```

The [`property`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) option define the entity property you want to use.

You can then customize your field using the "multiple" and "exanded" options to [behave the way you want](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons). Read [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: Why do you need to use a custom field? update your action with your code so that we can figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: because I want to create a separate field consisting of two select fields

Comment: Ok, So just use Entity Fields to define your select fields. It should work fine.

Comment: [Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html)  and [upload from config files or database](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service)

Comment: ther is:

**For example, suppose that you're storing the gender parameters in configuration:**

okej, so How get gender from datebase not from parameters in configuration

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20516/discussion-between-ahmed-siouani-and-pawel-brzoski)